# phpdoc not documenting anything but the starting docblock

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I'm trying to document a sample file:

```
/**
 * ElasticSearch Library
 *
 * Intended to do some cool stuff
 * 
 *
 * @author cmvr
 * @subpackage elasticSearch
 * @copyright free to use
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html Freely available under GPL
 */

namespace Libs;

/**
 * This is the main class of elastic search
 */

class elasticSearch {

    protected $dataConnection;

    /**
    * elastic search setup data connection
    * @return boolean
    */
    public function setupDataConnection($dataString) {
        return true;
    }


}
```

I'm running in the CLI:

```
phpdoc -f ../../app/libraries/elasticSearch.php -t ../../newDocs
```

And it's working fine, but when i'm viewing my html ouput here:

```
newDocs/files/elasticSearch.html
```

The class and the method setupDataConnection aren't documented at all.

This is the screens i see:
[image: class name and method aren't documented]

Can anyone explain what am i doing wrong?